# Is it possible to extract managed package metadata using Force.com IDE

Tags: managed-package, force.com, metadata

I tried to search online but I couldn't confirm that is it possible to extract managed package metadata using Force.com IDE? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can get majority of the meta data by adding the component details to your package xml. Following example should get the metadata from a custom object:

```
<types>
    <members>custom_object_in_managed_package__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

So the above addition will pull the meta data about a hypothetical custom object in a managed package "custom_object_in_managed_package__c".

Comment: Am I be able to make the changes in the managed package metadata and then deploy it back to Salesforce with Force.com IDE?

Comment: No you can't. To understand more about it, please read through https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_apps.htm

Comment: @SrinivasKoduru That's not entirely true. *Some* elements of the metadata are modifiable, and some can't even be upgraded.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Apologies for not able to understand what you said in the context of the original question. Can you please give me specific example?

Comment: See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm for details about what can be subscriber edited.

Comment: Got it, thank you, but my answer was more in the context of question than the generic.

Answer (score 1):

Managed package components and their attributes gets locked in subscriber org.
Hence subscriber can not able to view actual code.

For example, If we have apex class which is a part of managed package, we can not able to view its code in subscriber org.

Please go through the below link for Component and their behaviour in managed package.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm

Answer (score 0):

The Force.com IDE automatically extracts those files when you build a new package. They'll show up in the Referenced Packages folder. However, you can't update those files, because the IDE isn't meant to do that. For "customer configurable" managed package items, you could copy the Referenced Packages sub-folder for the package you want into a new location, then deploy those changes using another tool, such as Workbench, Mavensmate, etc.